# How to download a picture data in swift that is updated on rails by paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, paperclip, sdwebimage

I am worried about how to set the url in swift.I'd like to download and show the image using SDWebImage on swift. I've set url as following, but it cannot return picture. I cannot find out how to get style and basename automatically.

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension
```

I have been writing server side by RoR and upload the picture by paperclip.

Thank you for your help.

Rails

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers

  has_attached_file :photo, 
    :styles => { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
    :url  => "/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
    :path => "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension" 
  validates_attachment :photo, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
end
```

Swift

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("iconIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IconTableViewCell
let imageURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension")
        cell.iconView.sd_setImageWithURL(imageURL!)
return cell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need is the URL of your picture...Tell your ROR coder to send the URL of the picture in response from API...and if you are using `Alamofire` you can just simply try this

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://robohash.org/123.png").response { (request, response, data, error) in
        self.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data, scale:1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the question.By using jbuilder, I've got path of photo. Then I've shown the photo by SDWebImage.

user.rb

```
resource :users do
  desc "return a document"
  params do 
    requires :id, type:Integer
  end
  post ':get_picture', jbuilder:'users/picture' do
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

picture.jbuilder

json.(@user, :photo)